# Comparing DateTime structs to find free slots

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, scheduling

I would like to search through the events of all of the users in a list and retrieve all times where every user is free of 30mins or greater between 7AM-7PM.

There is a catch however, if a method is marked as 'recurring', ie the bit recurring is set to 1, then that event recurs for a period of 52 weeks after its beginning (so the time is not available). Retrieval of these events are taken care of in a stored procedure.

My code so far is below. Am I going about writing this procedure the right way? I'm not really sure how to proceed to get the function to return as I would like. Would anyone be able to help me with this?

```
List<string> usernames = //List of usernames.
DateTime start = //DateTime for start of period you would like to schedule meeting
DateTime end = //DateTime for end of period
//int mins = //duration of meeting (must be 30mins or greater)

foreach (string username in usernames) {
   //retrieve events for this user
    var db = Database.Open("mPlan");
    List<DateTime> startTimes;
    List<DateTime  endTimes;
    // This stored procedure returns all events of a user in a given time period, 
    // including recurring events.
    var record = db.Query("EXEC dbo.GetEvents @0, @1, @2", username, start, end);
    foreach(var record in result) {
          startTimes.Add(record.event_start);
          endTimes.Add(record.event_end);
    }
    // so now I have a list of all start times and end times of events
    // for one user and could save all this data in a list
  }
```

Table structure:

```sql
DECLARE @Users TABLE
(    
    UserID   INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Username VARCHAR(32)
);

DECLARE @Groups TABLE
(
    GroupID   INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    GroupName VARCHAR(32)
);

DECLARE @Membership TABLE
(
    UserID  INT,
    GroupID INT
);

DECLARE @event TABLE
(
    event_id    INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    event_start DATETIME,
    event_end   DATETIME,
    group_id    INT,
    recurring   BIT
);
```

**Example of functionality I would like :**

User adds multiple users from the database to a list. User selects a time period over which he would like to have a meeting with all of these users. My algorithm computes all time periods that are free for all users (i.e a times that would be suitable to have a meeting between all users and are >30mins ).

**Additional information :**

Sample cases :

- User A attempts to organize a meeting with User B. All timeslots are
  free. I would like the algorithm to return a DateTime start and
  DateTime end of all possible combinations of start times and end
  times that are >30mins and == duration ( a parameter ).
- Typical case : User A has events planned for all times except 6pm -
  7pm. He attempts to organize a meeting with user B for duration of
  1 hour. User B has no events organized - the DateTime 6PM and
  DateTime 7pm are returned to indicate the start and end time of
  meetings.
- Recurring case : User A has a recurring event at 5pm-6pm on a Monday.
  He tries to organize a meeting of 2 hours on a monday in six weeks time. All
  combinations of DateTime start and DateTime end where there is a difference of 2 hours       are returned. The time 5pm-7pm is
  not returned, since this event is recurring and occurs
  every week for 52 weeks.

Here is the stored procedure which retrieves all of a users events for a set time period (start, end):

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetEvents 
  @UserName VARCHAR(50), 
  @StartDate DATETIME, 
  @EndDate DATETIME 
AS 

BEGIN 
-- DEFINE A CTE TO GET ALL GROUPS ASSOCIATED WITH THE CURRENT USER 
;WITH Groups AS  
(   SELECT  GroupID  
    FROM    Membership  m 
            INNER JOIN Users u 
                ON m.UserID = u.UserID 
    WHERE   Username = @UserName 
    GROUP BY GroupID 
), 
-- DEFINE A CTE TO GET ALL EVENTS FOR THE GROUPS DEFINED ABOVE 
AllEvents AS 
(   SELECT  e.* 
    FROM    event e 
            INNER JOIN Groups m  
                ON m.GroupID = e.group_id 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  e.event_id, e.title, e.description, 
      DATEADD(WEEK, w.weeks, e.event_start), 
      DATEADD(WEEK, w.weeks, e.event_end), 
      e.group_id, e.recurring 
    FROM    event e 
            INNER JOIN Groups m  
                ON m.GroupID = e.group_id 
            CROSS JOIN  
            (   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) AS weeks 
                FROM    SYS.OBJECTS 
            ) AS w 
    WHERE  e.recurring = 1 
)    
-- GET ALL EVENTS WHERE THE EVENTS FALL IN THE PERIOD DEFINED 
SELECT  * 
FROM    AllEvents 
WHERE   Event_Start >= @StartDate 
AND     Event_End <= @EndDate 

END
```

Comment: Instead of showing the code you tried in .NET, perhaps you could show the table structure, some sample data and desired results?

Comment: @AaronBertrand , Thank you for the advice, I think I have edited my code appropriately now! If not please let me know and I will edit again :)

Comment: It's good that we can see the table structure, but now could you show us some actual sample data (e.g. a user with an event in the desired timeslot, a user who's available, and a user with a recurring event that overlaps with the desired timeslot), and which user(s) you'd want returned from that query.

Comment: As an additional comment, it is definitely not wise to call a stored procedure for every user in a loop. This is almost certainly something that can be solved in a single, set-based query with a single round-trip to the database. If you want to store the results in a `List` that's fine, but the approach you currently have is flawed. You want to minimize the chatter between application and database by letting each do the part they do best...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Many thanks for your feedback. I have added some sample data that I think explains what I am endeavoring to do better. It would be nice to solve this with a single round trip to the database, I'm not sure how that would be possible though.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have reread my sample cases and cleared up some points that my have been ambiguous before. I hope this is not the case now :)

Comment: I've formatted the table structure (again) in a format we understand and can easily re-use. And I'll suggest, again, to add *sample data* and not *word problems*.

Comment: Some further suggestions - why not show the algorithm you already have, which computes all time periods that are free? Also can you explain how it is known that a recurring event that happened on a Monday recurs every Monday, and not every weekday or every 5th of the month or every other Monday?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Many thanks for the work and feedback! I don't currently have an algorithm to compute all free time periods. That is what I was hoping to write! I will post up the stored procedure which retrieves all of a users events, it might help to show the function of the recurring bit better.  A recurring event occurs weekly, this is a standard I have decided to set. It cannot recur in any other pattern. The code above has been edited to include the stored procedure which computes all of a users events.

Comment: Thanks Simon, glad you are so grateful for my solution. It was an interesting problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I've learnt an invaluable amount from your code and guidance - more than I would have if I used all the resources at my disposal for hours at end. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Simon, not that I care about the rep I would have received, but just FYI the bounty was never granted. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128762/bounty-as-reward-instead-of-new-answer-bait

Comment: That is ridiculous. Do you know is there any way I can grant it to you? Can I set another bounty on the question and grant it to you? I know you don't care; but it's a really good example of a perfect answer that deserves the credit! Let me know what I can do and I will. Sorry about that :/

Comment: Not a problem Simon, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

So imagine some tables:

```sql
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(    
    UserID   INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Username VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Groups
(
    GroupID   INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    GroupName VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Membership
(
    UserID  INT,
    GroupID INT
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.[event]
(
    event_id    INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    event_start DATETIME,
    event_end   DATETIME,
    group_id    INT,
    recurring   BIT
);
```

And imagine that some sample data weren't so difficult to provide:

```sql
INSERT dbo.Users(Username) 
    SELECT 'User A' UNION ALL SELECT 'User B';

INSERT dbo.Groups(GroupName) 
    SELECT 'Group 1' UNION ALL SELECT 'Group 2';

INSERT dbo.Membership(UserID, GroupID)
    SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL SELECT 2,2;


INSERT dbo.[event](event_start, event_end, group_id, recurring)
-- user A, almost all day meeting on a specific date
SELECT '20120313 07:00', '20120313 18:00', 1, 0 

-- user A, recurring meeting every Monday
UNION ALL SELECT '20120312 17:00', '20120312 18:00', 1, 1 

-- user A, recurring meeting every Tuesday (future)
UNION ALL SELECT '20120327 14:00', '20120327 15:00', 1, 1; 
GO
```

Now we can build this stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetPossibleMeetingTimes
    @AskingUserID INT,
    @TargetUserID INT,
    @Duration     INT,           -- in minutes!
    @StartDate    SMALLDATETIME, -- assumes date, no time!
    @EndDate      SMALLDATETIME  -- again - date, no time!
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH dRange(d) AS
    (
        -- get the actual dates in the requested range
        -- limited to number of rows in sys.objects

        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1) 
            DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @StartDate)
         FROM (SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
          FROM sys.objects) AS x
    ), possible(ds, de) AS
    (
        -- get all the timeslots of @Duration minutes 
        -- between 7:00 AM and 7:00 PM for each day in 
        -- the range - these are all *potential* slots

        SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn, DATEADD(HOUR, 7, dRange.d)),
            DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*rn + @Duration, DATEADD(HOUR, 7, dRange.d))
        FROM (SELECT TOP (720/30) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.objects) AS x
        CROSS JOIN dRange
    )
    SELECT p.ds, p.de FROM possible AS p 
    WHERE p.de <= DATEADD(HOUR, 19, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, p.de), 0)) 
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM 
        (
            -- filter down to users with events on the days in the range

            SELECT group_id, event_start, event_end
                FROM dbo.[event] 
                WHERE event_start >= @StartDate 
                AND event_start < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
            UNION ALL 

            -- also include users with recurring events on same weekday(s)
            -- normalized to the matching day in the range

            SELECT group_id, 
              event_start = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, event_start, p.ds), event_start),
              event_end   = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, event_end,   p.ds), event_end)
            FROM dbo.[event]
            WHERE recurring = 1 
            AND event_start <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate) -- ignore future events
                    AND event_start >= DATEADD(WEEK, -52, @EndDate) -- 52 weeks out 
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, event_start, p.ds) % 7 = 0 -- same weekday
        ) AS sub
        WHERE sub.group_id IN 
        (
            -- this checks that events are within previously scheduled times

            SELECT GroupID FROM dbo.Membership
              WHERE UserID IN (@AskingUserID, @TargetUserID)
              AND (p.de > sub.event_start AND p.ds < sub.event_end)
        )
    )
    ORDER BY p.ds, p.de;
END
GO
```

Example calls:

```sql
-- Case 1: User A tries to meet with User B on a day where 
-- both schedules are clear.

EXEC dbo.GetPossibleMeetingTimes
    @AskingUserID = 1,
    @TargetUserID = 2,
    @Duration     = 30,
    @StartDate    = '20120314', -- no events for either user
    @EndDate      = '20120314';
```

Results:

[image: no events for either user]

```sql
-- Case 2: User A tries to meet with User B for an hour, on 
-- a day where user A has meetings from 7 AM to 6 PM.

EXEC dbo.GetPossibleMeetingTimes
    @AskingUserID = 1,
    @TargetUserID = 2,
    @Duration     = 60,
    @StartDate    = '20120313', -- user A has an almost all-day event
    @EndDate      = '20120313';
```

Results:

[image: user A is busy almost all day]

```sql
-- Case 3: User A tries to meet with User B for two hours, on 
-- a weekday where User A has a recurring meeting from 5-6 PM

EXEC dbo.GetPossibleMeetingTimes
    @AskingUserID = 1,
    @TargetUserID = 2,
    @Duration     = 120,        
    @StartDate    = '20120319', -- user A has a recurring meeting
    @EndDate      = '20120319';
```

Results:

[image: user A has a recurring meeting]

Now note that I took care of several factors you either haven't considered or haven't mentioned (such as a recurring event that starts in the future). On the other hand, I also didn't deal with some other factors (e.g. daylight savings time, if it may impact this at all) and didn't test all possible scenarios (e.g. multiple events on the same day that already exist).

I did test that if you pass in a range (e.g. 2012-03-12 -> 2012-03-14) you will essentially just get a union of the above results with roughly the same time slots made available (these vary based on duration of course). The important part is that the blackout timeslots are honored. I did not test the logic for the case where a recurring event starts in the future and the provided date range includes that weekday both before and after the first instance of the event.

If any case doesn't work for you, then this is exactly why it's important that you show us all your cases *using sample data, not word problems* and also explain the desired results of the query given that data.

**EDIT** - to handle more than 2 users, you only need a few changes. If you add a split function as follows:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts( @List VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN 
   ( SELECT Item = CONVERT(INT, Item) FROM (
      SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'INT') FROM (
       SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, ',', '</i><i>') 
         + '</i>').query('.')) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS y
       WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
```

Now very minor changes to the stored procedure (I've left out the unchanged bits):

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetPossibleMeetingTimes
    @UserIDList   VARCHAR(MAX),  -- removed other two parameters
    @Duration     INT,           
    @StartDate    SMALLDATETIME, 
    @EndDate      SMALLDATETIME  
AS
...
        WHERE sub.group_id IN -- changed the code within this subquery
        (
            SELECT GroupID FROM dbo.Membership AS m
              INNER JOIN dbo.SplitInts(@UserIDList) AS i
              ON m.UserID = i.Item
              WHERE (p.de > sub.event_start AND p.ds < sub.event_end)
        )
...
```

So then your call just changes slightly to:

```sql
EXEC dbo.GetPossibleMeetingTimes
     @UserIDList = '1,2,3,4,5',
     @Duration   = 30,
     @StartDate  = '20120314',
     @EndDate    = '20120314';
```

Just make sure that the requester is included in the comma-separated list.

PS this addendum is untested.

Comment: In he *real* world you could probably charge someone for half a days work. Here you get a +1 from me :).

Comment: Thanks Mikael. I'm starting to wonder if our profiles should have a PayPal link. :-)

Comment: Wow, amazing answer! Thank you so much for this! This is incredible! I will put a bounty for all of my reputation on this question and accept your answer in two days so you get all of the reputation! That's incredible, I am flabbergasted!

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've just been playing around with your amazing solution! It's so fast and useful! I was just wondering, since it's clear you're a huge level above me in this - is there an easy way to adapt this solution to work with multiple users? (i.e more than 2)? Apologies if I am pushing my luck, I just said I'd ask an expert rather than cobble something together myself :)

Comment: @SimonKiely I've updated the solution to allow for more than 2 users.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, ha, you've destroyed my solution again - it involved multiple loops through yours ! Thank you so much! Just one question, I get the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@Delimiter"." when I attempt to create the SplitInts procedure above. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Sorry, try now. Mixed two functions.

Comment: really great answer! +1  
my only 'remark' (kidding:) is whether this is too much for the SQL - and might belong to biz logic/C# more.

Comment: Nah, this is a question SQL can answer. Why push all the data to the app to have the app answer it instead? And what if there are multiple apps?

Comment: +1 for the great work and I really like how you commenting code!

Comment: You are awesome. Awesome. Awesome. Thanks a million times.

Comment: Hey @AaronBertrand, I know this is an old question but can you [help me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663779/stored-procedure-to-find-free-slots-with-different-work-times-per-day-of-the-wee)?